# Magento 301 redirect except Store views

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am having troubles understanding how to solve the following scenario:

- **site1.com** has *3 store views - 1,2,3*
- **site2.com** has only *1 store view*

I need to do a 301 redirect on **site1.com** *store 1* to **site2.com** and *keep the 2 and 3 store views as they are on site1.com*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Is possible using Magento URL Management to redirect links to external site? All i could find was how to redirect inside the same domain name.

I think i found it myself how to do it with .htaccess:
     RewriteCond $1 !^it
     RewriteCond $1 !^de
     RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site2.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: What do your urls for store views 2 and 3 look like? i.e. Do you have the store view id in URL's enabled? If so it may be possible for a htacess rewrite. If not the simplest thing I could think of doing would be to modify index.php to detect what the current site and store is and handle the redirect in there with php.

Comment: site1.com/storeview2/ and site1.com/storeview3/